# Scripts in footer in Wordpress custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i created a wordpress site, starting from one html template. 
I installed a naked theme, and modified header.php, footer.php ect adding the specific part of the html theme.

Now i have installed one plugin but it seem no to work.
I discovered that the plugin script was missing in the footer, there were only the html theme scripts.

Is there a specific method for add the plugins scripts into the custom footer.php?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`wp_head();` to **header.php** and `wp_footer();` to **footer.php** and plugins can load js or css when they need.